# How to fix exception:Resource not found: testdata/alphamap.png?

Tags: java, maps, slick, alpha, exceptions

I keep getting this exception:Resource not found: testdata/alphamap.png when trying to use Slick in my program. How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 1):

Google turned up with a fork of [slick](https://bitbucket.org/kevglass/slick) (not available anymore) here: [Slick Fork](https://github.com/ariejan/slick2d). When you go to the folder located under `testdata/alphamap.png` you will find it or [directLink](https://github.com/ariejan/slick2d/blob/master/testdata/alphamap.png).

You can resolve the error with simply placing it at the location it expects the file to be.